# Dense torus in $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

What is the dense torus in $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Is this the complement of all coordinate hyperplanes?

Is there only one possibility?

Comment: Yes it is the canonical one, the $[x_0:\ldots:x_n]$ with no $x_j=0$. Several others can be obtained by applying a $PGL_n$ linear transformation. And applying a non-linear automorphism of $\Bbb{A}^n$ you might  get much more: $\{ (x+y^2,y),(x,y)\in k^*\times k^*\}$ is a torus with multiplication $(x+y^2,y).(u+v^2,u)=(ux+(vy)^2,vy)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was confused because in the paper they say the dense torus, so I thought there is only one choice. In the paper the lattice of cocharacters is $=\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}/\mathbb{Z}(1,...,1)$, so I thought the torus is $=$Spec$([])$ with character lattice $$. But isn't this the complement of all coordinate hyperplanes or do I understand something wrong?